# Consuming nuget package containing .targets file via PackageReference

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I have .NET452 project - lets call it `Consumer.csproj` that I want to consume nuget lets call it `SharedTargets` that contained some custom targets files (`SharedTargets.targets`) from msbuild.

I'm using `PackageReference` format and now (compared to what it used to be) nuget packages are being restored to shared folder  (%userprofile%.nuget\packages), and I'm not sure if it is good idea to reference it via that (doesn't feel right).

Eg:

```
<PackageReference Include="SharedTargets">
  <Version>1.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
<Import 
  Project="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\SharedTargets\1.0\SharedTargets.targets"
/>
```

Also this works only in VS, running this from command line (`msbuild`) I'm getting chicken-egg problem:

> Confirm that the path in the `<Import>` declaration is correct, and that
>   the file exists on disk.

Obviously since I need to restore nuget first before I can use it :)

So question:

- is there some more elegant way how to resolve path to the nuget package inside project file
- is there a way how to make msbuild succeed (i.e. restore packages before `SharedTargets.target` is imported)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't try to manually import targets distributed via NuGet.

Put your .targets file inside a `build` subfolder inside the package and name it `SharedTargets.targets` (package id + `.targets`) and NuGet will automatically include the targets - for packages.config projects it will modify the project file on install and for PackageReference projects the targets will be imported by modifying an implicitly generated targets file in the `obj\` directory.

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) If you're up to I have a follow up question how to correctly reference .cs files from within such targets file - ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55286717/targets-file-withing-nuget-how-to-reference-content-cs-files