# .targets file within nuget package - how to include content files into a build

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I have a nuget package like:

```
/build/SharedTargets.targets
/content/File.cs
```

SharedTargets.targets looks like:

```
<Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\content\File.cs">
  <Link>File.cs</Link>
  <Visible>True</Visible>
</Compile>
```

Is there a way how to reference the content files in more elegant way ? I.E. how to construct relative path to content properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's basically how to do it.

I'd suggest not putting .cs files in the `content` subfolder since they might end up in the project directory on legacy packages.config projects.

If you are only using `PackageReference` to reference the package, you could use contentFiles instead - a NuGet feature that lets you add files with an associated build action (Compile, EmbeddedResource,...) logically to the build process without needing a .targets file. See [Using the contentFiles element for content files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#using-the-contentfiles-element-for-content-files)
for the underlying NuGet mechanism.